# REST URLs that don't list items

Tags: rest

Is it okay to use a URL like GET `/users/:user_id` in a REST API even if there should be no possibility to list users with GET `/users`?

If "yes" should GET `/users` return a 404 or an empty list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST has well defined constraints. You can read about them in the [Fielding dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

There is no constraint about how to design the URI structure, because the clients have to be completely decoupled from it. So this is not a REST concern.

To be short you can have nice URIs and use your custom conventions to build them. You have to be aware a few things only:

- a single URI can identify only a single resource (but a single resource can have multiple different URIs) - uniform interface constraint / identifying resources
- the URI path is hierarchical the query is non-hierarchical - URI standard (it can be subjective what is hierarchical and what not)
- the query is part of the URI (but you can have an own routing convention, for example a path can identify the resource and the query can describe the representation details)
- the URIs are mapped to resources and not to operations (as by SOAP), so if a human readable URI contains a verb, then the URI mapping is probably flawed

> If "yes" should GET /users return a 404 or an empty list?

If you don't want to show the user list to somebody, then you don't put a link in the responses pointing to the user list. If they call the URI manually, then you can send a 404 not found or a 403 forbidden, maybe a 401 unauthorized. Btw. if I were you I would show an user list containing the current user only.

Answer (score 1):

Since REST has no well defined standard you can do whatever you want, just document it accordingly and follow the same standard throughout your project.

Possibly 403 is a better option since there are users, but you are forbidden from listing them